# How do I return to a certain line or argument in a function in R?

Tags: r, function, loops, repeat

I have a function that validates a url based on input from a user. The way the function is set up, if the url doesn't validate (either because it doesn't exist or because it is a duplicate) the function simply ends.

How do I make it so that if the url isn't validated, the user goes back to the input dialogue to start the validation process over again instead of just ending the function?

```
exfun <- function(){
x <- toupper(readline("Do you want to do the function? Y/N......."))
if (x == "Y"){
writeLines("This is where the function body would be, but it's huge so for the sake of this StackExchange question, we'll just make it a simple thing")
} else 
writeLines("Well then why did you start the function? We'll try this again")
#This is where I would like the function to return to the "x<-...." line.
```

There are a few places where I would like to be able to "return to line X" as there are at least two validation points. I have it set up as a series of `if else` arguments which `else` into a message. How can I make it `else` into a message and bring the user back to the beginning/a previous validation test?

I fiddled with the `repeat` function, but couldn't get it to return from `if else` correctly.

Comment: Can't you just call `exfun` again there?

Comment: A while loop might fit the bill. That would keep returning to the start of the loop until you say it's ok to break out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really answering your question, but I'll give you an example that might help you (and probably someone will give a hint to improve this).

You can set a `while` loop and put conditions to continue the loop or to end it, simply like this:

```
i <- 1
while (T) {
  print(i)
  i <- i + 1

  if (i==5) {
    print("NEXT")
    next
  }

  if (i==10) break
}
```

As you see, the `if` with `next` conditions do something in your code, and keep running it after the command `print("NEXT")`. Also, the `break` is inside a condition to stop your loop.

I hope it helps, because with your example is difficult to give a full answer.